# Comparing Two Mutually Recursive Values for Equality in HSpec is Causing Problems

Tags: haskell, mutual-recursion, hspec

#### 1 The Context

Consider the following snippet of Haskell:

```
data T = T { f1 :: String 
           , f2 :: T
           } deriving (Eq, Show)

r1 = T { f1 = "val1"
       , f2 = r2 
       } :: T

r2 = T { f1 = "val2"
       , f2 = r1
       } :: T
```

Notice how `r1` is mutually recursive with respect to `r2`. AFAIK, this is totally fine in Haskell (as long as you don't use these two values in such a way that results in a mutually recursive calling loop that never terminates).  For example, a user of `r2` might want to access the value `f1 r1` via `f1 (f2 r2)`(which in this case "val1"). (In fact, this is how I'm trying to use these sorts of data structures in my own code.)

#### 2 The Problem

Now consider the following HSpec unit test:

```
describe "A mutually recursive value should be equal to itself" $ do
    r1 `shouldBe` r1
```

**This causes the test compiler to stall for a while and then eventually fail.**  Does this mean that there is something wrong with my code, or is this just a quirk of the way `shouldBe` is defined (I'm assuming the way it's checking for equality isn't lazy, and involves a mutually recursive, non-terminating call)? If this is just a quirk of HSpec's `shouldBe` function, then is there a way to check for equality between mutually recursive values? What I ultimately want to be able to do is something like the following:

```
r3 = T { f1 = "val1"
       , f2 = r2 
       } :: T

describe "A mutually recursive value should be equal to itself" $ do
    r1 `shouldBe` r3
```

Comment: the problem is your `Eq` instance (laziness does not matter - `shouldBe` is of course forcing them to the `Bool` result) (and `Show` too for that matter) those will loop forever - so you should implement those yourself - either with some form of *loop*-detection or without using the recursive values at all

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare infinite values in finite time.

Indeed, comparing infinite values is undecidable in general, so it's impossible for the compiler to generate an `Eq` instance which works on those.

To stress the point, consider this code:

```
complexCondition :: Integer -> Bool
complexCondition = ...

foo :: Integer -> T
foo n | complexCondition n = T { f1 = "found!", f2 = foo (n+1) }
      | otherwise          = T { f1 = "not yet", f2 = foo (n+1) }

reference :: T
reference = T { f1 = "not yet", f2 = reference }
```

We would have `foo 0 == reference` is and only if `complexCondition n` is false *for all* values `n`. This is unfeasible to check.

However, since the comparison problem on `T` is coRE (its complement is recursively enumerable), then we can semi-decide the complement. Indeed, the generated `Eq` instance will return `False` in finite time for different `T`s. This is feasible since only a finite prefix of such values need to be inspected to be able to state `False`.